# How to verify my project is using Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have downloaded and installed [Entity Framework 4.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2dc5ddac-5a96-48b2-878d-b9f49d87569a).  I have created a new project and added to it a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model.  How can I verify that this was created using 4.1 of the EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF 4.1 is just extension of EF 4.0 so you must use both EF 4.0 (System.Data.Entity.dll from GAC) and EF 4.1 (EntityFramework.dll from installation directory of EF 4.1) assemblies. If you added ADO.NET Entity Data Model it is just EF 4.0 because EF 4.1 must be added manually or probably by using DbContext Generator T4 template. EDMX is still EF 4.0 feature.

Comment: I think you're right.  I have added a reference now to the DLL and it is 4.1, so now what would be the easiest way to verify that I am getting 4.1 capabilities?

Comment: You must use them. There are no hidden capabilities which will be used automatically. You must use DbContext API either by using code-first or by generating `DbContext` from T4 template. Corner feature which can be used without DbContext API is strongly typed `Include`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your project references, they should be version: 4.1.10311.0 (based on your link).

Comment: Still seeing 4.0.  Which DLL in particular is the red herring?  System.Data.Entity is still showing up as v4.0.30319.  I also saw Sprocs in my wizard and I thought 4.1 discontinued support for them.